# Rotate sprite along the angle between two objects

Tags: java, libgdx, mathematics, rotation

Im trying to make flames follow my object, I set the direction for my moving object using the points between it and another object (using static destination for testing).

No matter what I do I cannot use the radians (which I use to set the direction), translate them to degrees, then rotate my flames so it looks like they are following it (like a comet).

What I try:

```
sprite.setPosition(pos.x, pos.y);
radians = Math.atan2(0 - pos.y, 540 - pos.x); //set radians
degrees = radians * 180 / MathUtils.PI; //calculate degrees
fireSprite.setPosition(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY());
fireSprite.setRotation((float)degrees); //rotate according to degrees
```

I move the object like this:

```
pos.x += 200 * Math.cos(radians) * delta;
pos.y += 200 * Math.sin(radians) * delta;
```

Am I missing something in the math? I feel like it should work.

An example of result from calculations:

```
radians: -1.8745297149164084, degrees: -107.4026382478209
radians: -1.1776894171295331, degrees: -67.47663130103584
radians: -2.1756410640936705, degrees: -124.65504723907603
radians: -1.2244578042111383, degrees: -70.15626242087843
```

The flames face the wrong direction, and not in a any sort of pattern I can use to debug my problem.

Comment: Why 540 - pos? Where does this come from? Try 0-pos.x...

Comment: As I said, Im using these values for testing. those values represent the bottom-mid of my screen

Comment: does rotation need to be in non-radians?

Comment: @Majte unfortunately yes, as far as I know.

Comment: you are calculating the angle between the bottom mid and the position of the object. How is this supposed to follow your object like a comet trait? You need to set the rotation to be the atan2 of the velocity vector of your moving object.

Comment: I just checked my game and the comet trail of my exploding rockets on my game engine are working in this way. I only get the angle of the objects speed vector and apply it to rotate the sprite.

Comment: @Majte I am, the angle is for the comet that is moving. Can you make an answer with what you mentioned in the last comment? what is working for u

Comment: Excuse me if I see this false or I don't have all the info, but in your code you are calculating the angle between a fixed point on the screen and the position of the sprite. This  has nothing to do with the speed of your object. So when your object turns after the explosion fire trail will be in the wrong direction

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, you have a point. Didnt even think this way. What if I remove the fixed point? Is there any way I can use the angle to move it and use that angle to set the degree rotation of my fire?

Comment: @Majte Is there any way you could show me how you do it? It would rly help if I could see an example of your solution

Comment: I use different functions and developed my own game engine in C++ and OpenGL, and thus I am not sure how compatible/useful that would be. The logic is the same as you present, except I use atan2(obj.vel_y, obj.vel_x) to set the rotation. Flame needs to trail the speed vector, not the positional vector. If this is still not working with you, there may be a problem with setRotation (or display) in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can try taking the vector from the ship (or whatever you have) to the target position, then get the angle of that. **libGDX**'s `Vector2` class has most of the methods you need.

Something like this might work for you;

```
// Get these from where ever you have them
Vector2 shipPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
Vector2 targetPosition = new Vector2(0, 540);

// Calculate the vector from the ship to the target
Vector2 fromShipToTarget = new Vector2(targetPosition).sub(shipPosition);

// Get the angle of the ship-to-target
float angle = fromShipToTarget.angle();

// Set the origin so that the sprite is rotated around its center, not its corner
fireSprite.setOrigin(fireSprite.getWidth() / 2.0f, fireSprite.getHeight() / 2.0f);
fireSprite.setPosition(shipPosition.x, shipPosition.y);
fireSprite.setRotation(angle);
```

The `angle` method on `Vector2` will give you the angle of the vector towards the positive y-axis so if you have two points **(0, 0)** and **(1, 1)** the above example will yield a vector of **45** degrees.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I use to get the angle of a 2d vector, hopefully it is what your are looking for. (using our own library functions, most of which should be obvious)

```
float zVec2f::getAngle () const
{
    //straight up, 0.0f degrees
    zVec2f up(0.0f, -1.0f);

    //angle between up vector and our vector
    zVec2f normal = *this;
    if ( normal.normaliseSafe() ) // returns true if it was possible to normalize vector
    {
        float angle = acosf(zDot(normal,up));

        //compensate for the fact that acos only
        //gives us 0->Pi (mirror along 180 degree line)
        if ( x < 0.0f)
        {
            angle += (2.0f * (zPIf - angle));
        }
        zASSERT(angle>=0.0f);
        zASSERT(angle<=zPI2f);

        return angle;
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: This function reinvents the wheel and is really too long. I can’t recommend anyone uses it. It can be rewritten in one single line: `float zVec2f::getAngle () const { return atan2f(this->x, - this->y); }`